# Excel formula/VBA that shows only a part of a column of another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

What I am trying to do is to show only a part of a column into another sheet through a formula.

Basically I have an Excel file in which I type in work shifts, as you can see on the example. The top of this table contains the date. The first column contains the name of the employee.

If possible I'd like to have the column of a specified date on another sheet (maintaining formatting), so that I can “sort” employees in their exact place without the need of swapping between Sheets.

The “blacked out” part is the one with employees names, the red-highlighted part is the one that should “appear” on the other sheet.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmZMo.jpg]

Comment: I don't exactly know what you want the output to look like. Will the output interact with the shown sheet above? Can you show an example of the output you want?

Comment: The output is the red highlighted part. If you type 01 of corse. If you type 02 (meaning 2nd of August), the output would be the next column.